# PHP Slim Application MongoDB - get request blocking post requests

Tags: php, mongodb, api, slim, restful-architecture

My system architecture is a web application server that runs LAMP stack with PHP-Slim 3 to serve as an API and also a web application front end. The API allows for both get requests to retrieve data, but also for sensor devices to POST to it, every second. On this same server, we run a processing algorithm written in Python that executes every 5 minutes to process 600 seconds worth of data.

The MongoDB sits on a separate server with it's own resources. In the beginning with few sensors, performance was good as you'd imagine. But over time, with indexes growing proportional to the amount of data, and also the increasing number of sensors posting data, the get requests from the web application front-end have slowed to a point that even displaying a graph causes a large delay which blocks the posting of the sensor data. This is a big issue and needs to be resolved for us.

I've been thinking that the web application probably needs splitting up into 3 components - one web-server for the POST API, one for the web application and another for handling API get requests. That way we'd have 3 individual connections to the MongoDB server and hopefully, we wouldn't have adverse blocking effects of get requests on posting data.

My question is, how would I start to go about doing this using PHP Slim?

Comment: Well, it doesn't sound like the problem is with Slim or can be solved with Slim alone.
Have you tried caching? You could cache denormalized/prepared for display data with Redis, for instance.

And could you please explain "processing algorithm written in Python that executes every 5 minutes to process 600 seconds worth of data"?

Comment: I'll look into caching because we're definitely not doing this at present. The processing algorithm takes a batch of the last 600s worth of sensor data and performs a number of different transformations to normalise the data (hence why this is done in Python). Its run as a crontab every 5 minutes and processed data for all sensor devices which have been live in the past 10 minutes. Scaling up with more sensors and continuous logging of data will take me into the big data area.

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't a slim problem it's a database problem. Your slim app likely just pulls the data from the DB... making the bottleneck either the time spent waiting for the db to response, or the transmission time for all the data to be sent from your DB to the slim app.

Try to figure out where the bottleneck is. Run the DB query in a CLI and see how long it takes to get the data locally ... if it's MBs of data, then transmission time even in a data center is going to be a problem.... I've seen crappy DCs have 500kbs, so even a few MB of data is going to be noticeably slow.